# Specified default entity container could not be found in the mapping and metadata information

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have gotten this error while compiling and I believe the problem is in my connection string which reads as such:

```
<add name="FDDEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=sql;initial catalog=FDD;persist security info=True;user id=FDD;password=notreallythepassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

(the problem I believe lies in metadata=res://*; as it seems to be missing the actual metadata, but how do I found out what should be going in there?)

The only confusion part of this project is that it actually uses entity framework and entity spaces at the same time, I'm working on porting over the entity spaces to entity framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help.  I noticed a difference between the metadata section of your connectionString and one of mine:

```
<add name="TrackerDataEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TrackerDataEntities.csdl|res://*/TrackerDataEntities.ssdl|res://*/TrackerDataEntities.msl;
```

Perhaps adding in the three files (.csdl, .ssdl, and .msl) like in my string will fix the issue.

Comment: Those files need to exist though right?  In order to reference them?

Comment: I would think so, but to be honest I'm not sure where they live.  Before posting, I checked my project folders to see where they live, but they do not seem to live with the rest of the project files.  The project this comes from does compile and run successfully, though.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it threw a new error, "Unable to find specified metadata resource."

Comment: I found where my files live, so the only other thing I can think of right now is to check and see if there are any files there that should be referenced:
`\obj\Debug\edmxResourcesToEmbed`

Comment: Mine is a web application so the structure is a little different, but none of these files exist and maybe they should.  Anyway something for me to think about.

Comment: Wasnt' entirely the answer, but it put me in the right place.  The missing files are required and I can't for the life of me explain why they were gone, but I ended up having to recreate the entity.

Answer (score 3):

This error can also occur when you re specifying an entity container with an incorrect entity set that does not correspond to it (happened with me).

```
ABCClass : ObjectContext {
public const string ConnectionString = "name=FDDEntities";
public const string ContainerName = "FDDEntities";

public ABCClass() : base(ConnectionString, ContainerName) { }

private ObjectSet<FDDEntity> _FDDEntity;

//Objects Creation
public ObjectSet<FDDEntity> FDDEntities
    {
        get
        {
            _FDDEntity = base.CreateObjectSet<FDDEntity>("FDDEntities");
            return _FDDEntity;
        }
    }
}
```

Where FDDEntities is the entity set of the entity 'FDDEntity'. You can find the name of the entity set by right clicking on the specified table in the model.edmx file and clicking on properties.